# Spring webFlux No subscriptions have been created for Kafka Streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-webflux, spring-kafka

i'm trying to publish message to a Kafka topic using spring web-flux, these are the configurations

```
@Bean
    public ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate<String, String> reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate(
            KafkaProperties properties) {
        Map<String, Object> props = properties.buildProducerProperties();
        return new ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate<String, String>(SenderOptions.create(props));



    }


@Bean
    public ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<String, String> reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplateTemplate(
            KafkaProperties properties) {
        Map<String, Object> props = properties.buildConsumerProperties();
        return new ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<>(ReceiverOptions.create(props));
    }
```

Then i try to stream all the values present in the topic

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/stream", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<String> postToKafka() {
    return consumerTemplate.receiveAtMostOnce().map(rec -> rec.value()).doOnNext(System.out::println);


}
```

but instead of getting data present in the topics i'm getting these error

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No subscriptions have been created
at reactor.kafka.receiver.ReceiverOptions.subscriber(ReceiverOptions.java:385) ~[reactor-kafka-1.3.3.jar:1.3.3]
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
*__checkpoint ⇢ Handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide topics to consume from.
See these options of the `ReceiverOptions`:

```
/**
 * Sets subscription using manual assignment to the specified partitions.
 * This assignment is enabled when the receive Flux of a {@link KafkaReceiver} using this
 * options instance is subscribed to. Any existing subscriptions or assignments on this
 * option are deleted.
 * @return options instance with new partition assignment
 */
@NonNull
ReceiverOptions<K, V> assignment(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions);

/**
 * Sets subscription using group management to the specified collection of topics.
 * This subscription is enabled when the receive Flux of a {@link KafkaReceiver} using this
 * options instance is subscribed to. Any existing subscriptions or assignments on this
 * option are deleted.
 * @return options instance with new subscription
 */
@NonNull
ReceiverOptions<K, V> subscription(Collection<String> topics);

/**
 * Sets subscription using group management to the specified pattern.
 * This subscription is enabled when the receive Flux of a {@link KafkaReceiver} using this
 * options instance is subscribed to. Any existing subscriptions or assignments on this
 * option are deleted. Topics are dynamically assigned or removed when topics
 * matching the pattern are created or deleted.
 * @return options instance with new subscription
 */
@NonNull
ReceiverOptions<K, V> subscription(Pattern pattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

for streaming we need to add receiver options so in the configuration i made the following changes

```
@Bean
    public ReceiverOptions<String, String> 

kafkaReceiverOptions(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        ReceiverOptions<String, String> basicReceiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.create(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties());
        return basicReceiverOptions.subscription(Collections.singletonList("topic_name"))
                .addAssignListener(receiverPartitions -> System.out.println("onPartitionAssigned "+ receiverPartitions))
                .addRevokeListener(receiverPartitions -> System.out.println("onPartitionsRevoked "+ receiverPartitions));
    }
```

and in the consumerTemplate

```
@Bean
    public ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<String, String> reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplateTemplate(
            ReceiverOptions<String, String> kafkaReceiverOptions) {
        return new ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<>(kafkaReceiverOptions);
    }
```